# C++ For Loop returns matched values multiple times

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, match

I am attempting to match strings input by the user to certain elements in my vectors, and then if they are a match, add all the information to a new matched vector which could then be output to the user. However my program seems to find the match/matches and then store them multiple times (so my matched vector is populated with the same data 4/5 times).

Here is my code for the matchings:

```
cout << "Please enter your airport of Departure.\n e.g. EMA \n\n";

cin >> depCode;

cout << "\nPlease enter your destination.\n e.g. VIE \n\n";

cin >> destCode;

cout << "\nPlease enter your date of travel.\n e.g. 12/06/15 \n\n";

cin >> dateTravel;


        for(int i=0; i<flights.size();++i){
            for(int j=0; j<airports.size();++j){
                if(flights[i].originAirport == depCode && flights[i].destinationAirport == destCode){
                    string oAirport = flights[i].originAirport; //airports[j].airportCode;
                    string dAirport = flights[i].destinationAirport; //airports[k].airportCode;
                    string Airline = flights[i].Airline;
                    int Price = flights[i].airlinePrice;
                    int departureTax = airports[j].departureTax;
                    int Duration = flights[i].Duration;
                    matched.push_back(matchedFlights(oAirport,dAirport,Airline,Price,departureTax,Duration));
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very confused at this point. I am  a beginner so I am sorry if its a very obvious mistake.

Comment: Could it just be finding multiple matches?

Comment: Why do you need to cycle through the airports? To find a matching flight you only need the external cycle.

Comment: The way you did it, whenever you find a matching flight, you put it in the matched vector n times, where n is the number of airports you have.

Comment: no im fairly certain its not, the vectors were filled with data from some .txt files and there are only a few sets of data in them. Also the matches that are found are the exact same match (the correct one mind you) but output 4/5 times.

Comment: @lodo That sounds likely! Infact double checking it does seem to be outputting the matches in multiples of the number of airports

Comment: Well you are looping once with your outer loop and looping n times with your inner loop all while `i` is staying the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement is begin executed with the same conditions for every element in your airports vector, even though the if statement only uses values from the flights vector, thus creating duplicates.  You may want to rethink your logic, and if/how you should use the inner loop.

Comment: Yes that looks like its solved it, I have removed the inner for loop, thank you for the help!

Comment: @Tab If this answer solved your problem you should rather accept it using the big white checkmark in the left of it, than just commenting _"Thank you"_.